# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/util/ReaderInputStream vaadin+gradle+intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, vaadin

I have been working fine with `Vaadin + Gradle + IntelliJ` until yesterday night when I introduced SLF4J(logback) logging to my application. Since then I can't make my project anymore due to `classDefFoundError` of `org/apache/tools/ant/util/ReaderInputStream`.

I can't link it with any transitive dependency of any contained jar in application, but even if I remove `SLF4J` libraries I still can't make my application, so I am wondering what changed?

I am using `vaadin gradle plugin 0.9.5` and `gradle 2.2.1`. Has anyone ever encountered this problem? I was reading another post where someone had the same issue, but the solution he proposed is not valid to my application. He proposed to comment some of the lines in `vaadin.gradle`, which my application doesn't have.

Comment: Have you made a clean build? Sometimes we just get left over compiles class files...

Comment: @AndréSchild i have performed clean build for both application and artifact without any luck.

Comment: Final i have restarted the computer and now its working...! i think intelliJ where out of sync with gradle or something...! thanks @AndréSchild for showing me some light

Answer (score 96):

Try

File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Comment: I have had to do this soooo many times once I switched to IDEA, kind of sad.

Comment: Ah perfect. I had wasted hours on this!

Comment: Simply restarting the IDE was enough for me. Might try that before invalidating caches.

Answer (score 9):

`File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...` nor did `git clean -dfx`. Here is what I had to do:

1. Close IntelliJ
2. IMPORTANT: Make sure you have everything commited you care about (you're about to clean your working copy)
3. Run `git clean -dfx` to clean your working copy
4. Run IntelliJ
5. Select `Import Project`
6. Navigate to the directory containing your project
7. The select `Import project from external model` and select Gradle
8. Press Next
9. Make sure the settings on the next page look ok then press Finish
10. The build should now hopefully work

Comment: Yeah basically re-importing the project from existing sources worked for me.  I didn't have to invalidate caches or run `git clean`.

Comment: What a mess! I've got all sorts of run configurations I'd have to recreate if I did this.

Answer (score 9):

I deleted the `.idea` folder and that worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

`File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...` option didn't work for me, but

`sudo git clean -dfx` worked fine

Comment: That command removes everything that isn't bring tracked by git. Specifically all of intellij's state. Sometimes intellij just goes a bit wrong and needs resetting

Answer (score 2):

remove .idea and invalidating caches worked for me.

1. `rm -r .idea/` in command line
2. in Intellij GUI File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...